# How to display the blob image stored in mysql using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, blob

I want to receive the blob image stored in the longblob type 'menuImg' column and put it in the img tag with the id 'img'.
Help me!

['/admin/getMenuImg' Router source]

```
router.get('/getMenuImg', function (req, res) {
    //var menuNo = req.body.menuNo;
    var query = `SELECT menuImg FROM menu WHERE menuNo = 1`;

    connection.query(query, function (error, result) {
        if(error) {
            console.log("error ocurred: ", error);
            res.json({ "code": 400, "result": "error ocurred" })
        } else {
            console.log("get menuImg success");
            res.json({"code": 200, "result": "get menuImg success", "menuImg": result[0].menuImg})
        }
    })
})
```

[html source]

```
<body>
    <img id="img" width="400" height="400">
</body>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url:'/admin/getMenuImg', // Maybe this is wrong
        cache:false,
        xhr:function(){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType= 'blob'
            return xhr;
        },
        success: function(data){
            var img = document.getElementById('img');
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            img.src = url.createObjectURL(data.menuImg);
        },
        error:function(){
            
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should return the image itself instead of JSON - and then don't try to access the BLOB as JSON (I refer to the non-existent `data.menuImg` property)

Comment: I thought about it for a few days, but it was solved right away as you said! Thank you so much :)